# Can ArcMap basemaps be used in figures intended for publication?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online-basemaps, license

Can the 'imagery' basemap available in ArcMap 10 be used as part of a figure in a scientific publication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9) page about the ESRI World Imagery basemap with links to a [Summary](http://downloads2.esri.com/ArcGISOnline/docs/tou_summary.pdf) and [Terms of Use](http://www.esri.com/legal/pdfs/mla_e204_e300/english.pdf). The [Summary](http://downloads2.esri.com/ArcGISOnline/docs/tou_summary.pdf) says "You May: Include screen captures or a printed or plotted maps in the following ways... In academic publications (research journals, textbooks, etc.)"

Answer (score 7):

[FAQ: What is the correct way to cite an ArcGIS Online basemap?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012040#:%7E:text=When%20an%20ArcGIS%20Online%20basemap,task%2C%20or%20application%20being%20used)  suggests that you *should* be able to but you will need to follow the advice therein about how to cite and where to find Terms of Use for the particular basemap(s) you are intending to use:

> When an ArcGIS Online basemap is used in ArcGIS Online content that is
> published, the acceptable method of attribution is by crediting the
> sources found in the Credits field of the [item details](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/item-details.htm) for each
> ArcGIS Online map, task, or application being used. Credits should
> also be displayed in the lower right corner of the map or image.